# Print not executing

Tags: python

My print() at the final lines are not executing, I have tried simply indenting them however, the variable [age_1] will be undefined.
Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

birth_year = input("When were you born? ")
time = datetime.now()
year = int(time.strftime("%Y"))
age = year - int(birth_year)
print(age)

answer = input(f"So, you're {age}, yes? ")

if answer == "No" or answer == "no" or answer == "NO":
    other_age = input("I am sorry, perhaps I miscalculated, can you input your birth year once more? ")
    
    if age == other_age:
# Problem part
     print(f"""
    Hold on...You were lying about me being incorrect!
    So you are {age}!
    """)
```

When i run the code, the others work fine but the print statement at that last part doesn't show when i run the code

Comment: Probably a string vs into issue, put an else in there and print their classes.

Comment: You don't process `other_age` the same as you do with `birth_year`. And anyway you are asking the user for their birth year again, but comparing it with their age that you calculated.

Comment: You are not converting `other_age` to an `int`, but you're comparing it to `age` which is an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @quamara and @Kemp's comments above, I suggest you define a function to calculate the age from the user's response to your questions. This is not necessarily the code I would use, but I just moved your code around a little bit so you can more easily understand what I have done.

```
from datetime import datetime

# define a function to calculate age from birth year    
def age_from_birth_year(prompt):
    birth_year = input(prompt)
    time = datetime.now()
    year = int(time.strftime("%Y"))
    age = year - int(birth_year)
    return age

age = age_from_birth_year("When were you born? ")
print(age)

answer = input(f"So, you're {age}, yes? ")

if answer == "No" or answer == "no" or answer == "NO":
    other_age = age_from_birth_year("I am sorry, perhaps I miscalculated, can you input your birth year once more? ")
    
    if age == other_age:
# Problem part
     print(f"""
    Hold on...You were lying about me being incorrect!
    So you are {age}!
    """)
```

Answer (score 0):

`other_age` is the string input, i.e the year of birth.

So here you need to again calculate the age after the input just like you did in the first input, the your condition will work and print out the output successfully.

Add this after `other_age` input:

`other_age = year - int(other_age)`

Answer (score -2):

You must compare
if year==other_age:

Not
if age==other_age